# Why is my code not working correctly?

Tags: java

I am kinda new to coding. So, I was wondering why isn't my code working correctly? If you run the code, it asks you the correct value and then prints out if you are correct or not. But it also prints out the "else" statement.

```
package MyFirstProject;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFirstProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int answer;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is 5 + 5");
        answer = scanner.nextInt();

        if(answer == 10){
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        }if(answer == 9){
            System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
        }if(answer == 11){
            System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need `else`s after every `if`, not just the last one.

Comment: you're missing a bunch of `else if (...)`

Comment: You structured this like a switch statement. Yes else ifs is what you want. That said we generally see things like this on noobie friendly sites like bignerdranch

Comment: Follow this one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Note that the only reason you need the `else`s is the big blanket `else` at the very end. It would be okay without them, since the answers don't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace if with else if:

```
    if(answer == 10){
        System.out.println("You are correct!");
    } else if(answer == 9){
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
    } else if(answer == 11){
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
    } else{
        System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
    }
```

In your example else was matched with the last if statement, so it was not the 'last resort' choice. You need to grab all ifs into a single chain, so that else will match all cases where non if is matched.

Or use switch:

```
switch(answer):
   case 10:
      System.out.println("You are correct!");
      break;
   case 9:
   case 11:
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
        break;
   default:
        System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with if statements. Else is connected with last if statement. It will trigger every time whenever answer value is not "11". You need to use "else if" as shown below.

```
 if(answer == 10){
        System.out.println("You are correct!");
    }else if(answer == 9){
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
    }else if(answer == 11){
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use else**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int answer;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is 5 + 5");
    answer = scanner.nextInt();

    if(answer == 10){
        System.out.println("You are correct!");
    }else if(answer == 9){
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
    }else if(answer == 11){
        System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that you are missing ELSE before second and third IF.

```
if(answer == 10){
    System.out.println("You are correct!");
}else if(answer == 9){
    System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
}else if(answer == 11){
    System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
}
```

In your case third IF was not true so else was executed. With my fix and 10 as input value first IF will be true and then all remaining will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that if for example

```
answer == 10 // YES - It'll print "You are correct!"
answer == 9 // No - Skip to the next If block
answer == 11? // No - skip to the else and print "You are wrong! Try again!"
```

So the correct way to make sure it only checks one block and prints the right message this is what you do:

```
if(answer == 10){
    System.out.println("You are correct!");
} else if(answer == 9){
    System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
} else if(answer == 11){
    System.out.println("You were close! Try again!");
} else{
    System.out.println("You are wrong! Try again!");
}
```